# How to run my project so that they use my AspectJ aspects

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj

I am a beginner to AspectJ. I am using it to take screenshots in my webdriver programs. Following is my package structure.

[image: Project Structure]

I want to know that how do I run my programs in Browser class so that it uses AspectJ aspects defined in the Screenshots class.

Right now when I run my tests as TestNG tests in eclipse the aspects do not run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that you have AspectJ Development Tools plugin installed
2. Convert your project to AspectJ project using context menu Configure/Convert to AspectJ project

Your project should work now using internal aspects. If the aspects are external - put them on your class path.

Comment: No problem. Giving smart-assed advice like RTFM, even though it is a valid advice, is maybe not worth to be a stand-alone answer. ;-)